# Como encuentro el punto medio de dos números en java

Tags: java

```
public class T6_NumMedio {
    public static int num1, num2;
    public static float puntoM, contador = 0;
    public static float NumMedio() {

        /*esto hara un conteo para encontrar los numeros que hat entre el 
primero y el segundo numero para a si encontrar el punto medio*/
         for ( int i = num1; i < num2; i++) {
             contador ++;
             puntoM = contador / 2 ;
        }
        return puntoM;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
        num1 = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
        num2 = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println(NumMedio());
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, evita las exclamaciones en el título de la pregunta debido a que significa "urgencia", "estado agresivo en la Informatica", etc. Creo que el "sxfbadfvasdf gs gwgt rg rrg qgrqgrweqg erg rewqtg werg rewg qrgwerg rweg erg rewgq" sobra en tu pregunta. La edito.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres sacar la media de los números? Es decir, A=4 B=12, que el resultado sea ¿6?

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quiere decir tu enunciado, pero si lo que quieres es **conseguir el punto medio -el número medio- de entre dos números** agregados por teclado, una posible solución sería la siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication133 {
    public static int n1, n2;

    public static float NumMedio(int n1, int n2) {
        return (n1+n2)/2;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
        n1 = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
        n2 = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println(NumMedio(n1, n2));
    }
}
```